# String-ConfigurationProperty within custom ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationsection

I've got the following `ConfigurationSection` in one of my libs in my solution (let's say `LibA.dll`):

```
public class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("proxy", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = false)]
    public string HttpProxy
    {
        get { return (string) this["proxy"]; }
        set { this["proxy"] = value; }
    }
}
```

In the `App.config` of my executable I'm using the `Section`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="liba"
             type="LibA.MyConfigurationSection, LibA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"></section>
  </configSections>
  <liba>
    <proxy>abc</proxy>
  </liba>
</configuration>
```

First of all visual studio tells me that it can't find any schema.
Secondly, the following line throws an exceptions:

```
MyConfigurationSection myConfiguration = (MyConfigurationSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("liba");
```

> The proxy-Property is no ConfigurationElement.

Can't I use the type string within a `Configuration` section? Do I really have to create a custom `ConfigurationElement`?

Comment: You have declared the proxy as a property, so the xml should be something like this <liba proxy="abc" ></liba>

Comment: Wow, it was really that easy. Thanks! Post it as answer, so I can mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code the 'proxy' is an attribute of the 'liba' element. The xml should be in the following format

```
<liba proxy="abc"></liba>
```